# How do I set the font in a StaticResource?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to define the FontAwesome fontFamily in the App.xaml so I can use staticresource in my code.

Setting the fontFamily directly in the page is working. Problem is when I try to get this value from the StaticResource I have a blank page showing.

App.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<prism:PrismApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Unity;assembly=Prism.Unity.Forms"
             x:Class="RedPrairie.App">
    <Application.Resources>

        <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- Font Awesome fonts path per plateform -->
            <OnPlatform x:Key="FontAwesomeBrands" x:TypeArguments="x:String"  Android="FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Font Awesome 5 Brands Regular"  iOS="Font Awesome 5 Free" />
            <OnPlatform x:Key="FontAwesomeSolid" x:TypeArguments="x:String" Android="FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid"  iOS="Font Awesome 5 Free" />
            <OnPlatform x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular" x:TypeArguments="x:String" Android="FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular"  iOS="Font Awesome 5 Free" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

My Page:

```xml
            <Label Text="{x:Static model:Icon.far_user}" 
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeRegular}"
                       FontSize="Large"
                       TextColor="SkyBlue"
                       VerticalOptions="Center">

            </Label>
```

working Page :

```xml
<Label Text="{x:Static model:Icon.far_user}" 
                       FontSize="Large"
                       TextColor="SkyBlue"
                       VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label.FontFamily>
                    <OnPlatform 
                     x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                     Android="FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular" 
                     iOS="Font Awesome 5 Free"  />
                                    </Label.FontFamily>

            </Label>
```

Another working Page :

```xml
<Label Text="&#xf007;" 
                       FontSize="Large"
                       TextColor="SkyBlue"
                       VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label.FontFamily>
                    <OnPlatform 
                     x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                     Android="FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular" 
                     iOS="Font Awesome 5 Free"  />
                                    </Label.FontFamily>

            </Label>
```

Content of class Icon :

```
  public static class Icon
    {
        /*Regular Icons - prefixed with FAR_*/

        public static string far_address_book = "\uf2b9";
        public static string far_address_card = "\uf2bb";
        public static string far_angry = "\uf556";
        public static string far_arrow_alt_circle_down = "\uf358";
        public static string far_arrow_alt_circle_left = "\uf359";
        public static string far_arrow_alt_circle_right = "\uf35a";
        public static string far_arrow_alt_circle_up = "\uf35b";
        public static string far_user = "\uf007";
...
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where did you put your FontAwesome5Regular.otf file? Have you read this: https://medium.com/@tsjdevapps/use-fontawesome-in-a-xamarin-forms-app-2edf25311db4 ?

Comment: Hi Roubachof, yes I read that post (and even posted a comment in there some times ago). The files are located in the Android's Asset folder. Setup seems ok because I can get it work without using static resource !
Problem is when I'm using StaticResource to avoid repeating useless code.

Comment: can we see your entire `App.xaml` ?

Comment: updated above, but there's not much inside it

Comment: maybe if you use <prism:PrismApplication.Resources> instead of  <Application.Resources> ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I discovered that issue only occurs when I have both Label text and FontFamily set to Static variable / resource. And I don't have issue if I hard code one or the other field

Comment: Is the issue solved ?

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the font filename and use font names as shown below.

It seems that Android is not strict on the font name, however, if the font filename is incorrect a RuntimeException: 'Font asset not found ' is thrown.

On iOS, if the font filename is incorrect in the `UIAppFonts` array key in `Info.plist`, or the font name is incorrect, the glyph/text appears as a question mark within a frame.

On UWP, with an incorrect font filename or font family name, the glyph/text appears just as a frame.

Font file location and content type in project:

iOS: Font file location: `Resources` folder. Content type: `BundleResource`

Android: Font file location: `Assets` folder. Content type: `AndroidAsset`

UWP: Font file location: `Assets` folder. Content type: `Content`

`ResourceDictionary`:

```
  <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="FaRegular">
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="FontAwesome5Free-Regular" />
    <On Platform="Android" Value="FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Font Awesome Regular" />
    <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
  </OnPlatform>

  <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="FaSolid">
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="FontAwesome5Free-Solid" />
    <On Platform="Android" Value="FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Font Awesome Solid" />
    <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
  </OnPlatform>

  <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="FaBrands">
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="FontAwesome5Brands-Regular" />
    <On Platform="Android" Value="FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Font Awesome Brands" />
    <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/FontAwesome5 Brands.otf#Font Awesome 5 Brands" />
  </OnPlatform>
```

Example `Label`:

```
<Label Text="&#xf2b9;" TextColor="Accent" FontFamily="{StaticResource FaRegular}" />
<Label Text="&#xf641;" TextColor="Accent" FontFamily="{StaticResource FaSolid}" />    
<Label Text="&#xf26e;" TextColor="Accent" FontFamily="{StaticResource FaBrands}" />
```

For iOS add the following using Open With > XML editor in `Info.plist`:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
<string>FontAwesome5Brands.otf</string>
<string>FontAwesome5Regular.otf</string>
<string>FontAwesome5Solid.otf</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this isn't working. I've downloaded again, use same names etc etc.
I tried to copy exact same method in a blank project and.. it works! Something is not correct in my project but how can I identify the problem? the view is starting completely blank.

Comment: some more tests tends to tell me that issue is with my App.xaml ! If I move the resource dictionari to the page, then it's working. What can cause such issue ?

Comment: Pretty silly! My App.xaml.cs contained a second constructor which didn't included  public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer) : base(initializer) { InitializeComponent(); } Is it normal that I have to use dynamicresource and not staticresource ?